# Changing attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I hope someone can help.  I have a link like this:

```
<a id='testOne' onclick="doTest('one'); return false;" title="Test One">One</a>
```

What I need is to have jQuery do the following:

- remove the title and disable the action of the link
- add back the title "Test One" and enable the action of the link

Are there any jQuery experts out there who could show me how to do this. Right now my jQuery knowledge is just selectors and almost nothing more. I hope I can get an example.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery has documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ It's worth having a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
//To remove the title and default action.
$("#testOne").attr("title", "").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}).attr("onclick", null);

//To reset the title and action
$("#testOne").attr("title", "Test One").click(function(e){
  doTest('one');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

`$('#testOne').attr('title', '').attr('title', 'Test One').attr('href', 'someLink');`

`attr()` gets or sets an attribute, and you can chain commands together.

If by 'enable the action of the link' you mean simulate a click, try this:

`$('#testOne').trigger('click');`

You can alternatively skip your `onclick` syntax and do:

`$('#testOne').click(function (ev) {doTest('one');});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.attr()` to edit attributes, for example:

```
$('#testOne').attr('title', '');
$('#testOne').attr('onclick', '');

$('#testOne').attr('title', 'Your old title');
$('#testOne').attr('onclick', 'Your old onclick');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the inline code of the element (i.e. the `onclick=...` part) then you'll have to use such code:

```
var actionsMapping = {};

function Disable() {
    var oLink = $("#testOne").get(0);
    if (oLink.onclick != null)
        actionsMapping[oLink] = oLink.onclick;
    oLink.onclick = null;
}

function Enable() {
    var oLink = $("#testOne").get(0);
    if (actionsMapping[oLink] != null)
        oLink.onclick = actionsMapping[oLink];
}
```

The attributes collection can store only string literals, while you need to store actual event handlers.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/g9p56/).

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, you should apply your handler initially using jQuery.  It will be easier to disable, using some "global" state, than to reapply.

```
<a id='testOne' title="Test One">One</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       var testOneClicked = false;
       $('#testOne').click( function() {
           if (testOneClicked) {
              $(this).attr('title','Test One');
           }
           else {
              $(this).attr('title','');
              doTest('one');
           }
           testOneClicked = !testOneClicked;
           return false;
       });
    });
</script>
```

With a bit of experimentation, you can extend this, using arrays and the [index](http://api.jquery.com/index) method, to account for any number of links providing that they work similarly.  All you need to do is keep track of the arguments to the `doTest` function and the titles in a set of arrays that correspond to the links relative position among the set of links and extract these based on the link's index at the time that it is clicked.