# How to add a new element in the current object?

Tags: jquery

There is the following JQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".translated").mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).html("<input type='text'/>");
        });
    });
```

And there is the table with many `<div class="translated">` items with text in it. I need to replace text in div block to input item by mouseenter event. It works. But I also need to set attributes for input element in the process of replacing, and I don't know how I can do it because I'm new in JS/JQuery. Please, give me some info. Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: sorry, my attributes is calculated with JS too, it isn't constant.

UPDATE 2: 
Algorithm:
1) Insert input item in div item 
2) Change height of the new inserted item

Comment: Just set the rest of the input attributes as you are setting the `type="text"` or use `$('<input />').attr({type: 'text'/*, more attributes*/});`

Comment: What attributes are you trying to set, and why can't you simply write them into the `<input ... />` tag definition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing attributes with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972911/changing-attributes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, there's a special jQuery syntax for element creation.

```
$("<input/>", {
    type: "text",
    height: 100
}).appendTo(this);
```

The above inserts an `input` element with `type` attribute set to `text` and `height` (CSS) set to `100px`.

The generated markup appended to the target element is:

```
<input type="text" style="height: 100px;">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Please, tell me, need I use "new" keyword for making new input item? Please, give the full code

Comment: That's enough for your needs

Answer (score 3):

Just set the rest of the input attributes as you are setting the `type="text"` like below,

```
$(this).html("<input type='text' /* other attributes */ />");
```

or use like below,

```
$('<input />').attr({type: 'text'/*, more attributes*/});
```

Comment: but if I use your last construction I'll change all input items on the page right? I need to change height attr only for a new item.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var someVariable = 1 + 2;
 $(this).html("<input type='text' anotherAttribute='something' attrFromValue='" 
     + someVariable + "' />");
```